# use auto layout to position 3 image view pragmatically the same height

Tags: swift, view, autolayout, constraints

My code below declare 3 image views. I would like all of them to have the same height and fill up the uiview. It should look like this photo below

[image]

I need to somehow get the image views to interact with each other but I dont know how. This should be done in all code. No storyboard used.

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var pic = UIImageView()
var pic2 = UIImageView()
var pic3 = UIImageView()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [pic,btn].forEach({
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview($0)
        $0.backgroundColor = .systemRed
    })
    pic3.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
       pic2.backgroundColor = .systemPink


    pic.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    pic.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -200).isActive = true
    pic.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    pic.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true

    pic2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    pic2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
    pic2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    pic2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true

    pic3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    pic3.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
    pic3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    pic3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
}
}
```

Comment: Put them in a `UIStackView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use autolayout constraints: align the edges and then use the view's (or SafeAreaLayoutGuide's) height anchor with a multiplier of a third.  To allow for rounding, only assign the height anchor to two of the three views and use top/bottom anchors to set the height of the remaining view.

```
   let view1 = UIView()
   view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   view1.backgroundColor = .blue
   let view2 = UIView()
   view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   view2.backgroundColor = .yellow
   let view3 = UIView()
   view3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   view3.backgroundColor = .purple
   view.addSubview(view1)
   view.addSubview(view2)
   view.addSubview(view3)

   //set constraints
   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      // anchor edges
      view1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
      view1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
      view2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
      view2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
      view3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
      view3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
      // set anchors governing height
      view1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
      view2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view1.bottomAnchor),
      view2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view3.topAnchor),
      view3.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
      view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/3),
      view2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/3)
   ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution using `UIStackView`:

(disclaimer: typed in browser, not tested in Xcode)

Also, you still may need auto layout to make the stackView cover the screen.

```
var view1 = UIView()
var view2 = UIView()
var view3 = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view1.backgroundColor = .blue
    view1.backgroundColor = .green
    view1.backgroundColor = .red

    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [view1, view2, view3])  

    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually

    self.view.addSubview(stackView)

}
```